# Can I pass a parameter to an Array.prototype.some() callback?

Tags: javascript

Take a look at this piece of code:

```
var array = [0, 1];

var even = function(element, index, array, considerZeroEven) {
  // checks whether an element is even
  if (element === 0)
    return considerZeroEven;

  return element % 2 === 0;
};

console.log(array.some(even)); // Here I should do the trick...
```

Is it possible to pass to even the considerZeroEven parameter?

I saw I should use thisArg and do something dirty inside there, but I do not think this is a good idea, and looking at [the polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill) it looks like it will pass only the value of the element, the index of the element, and the array object being traversed, so nothing more could be done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could take a closure over the wanted value of `considerZeroEven` and take just a function as callback without using `thisArg`.

```js
var array = [0, 1],
    even = function (considerZeroEven) {
        return function(element, index, array) {
            return element === 0
                ? considerZeroEven
                : element % 2 === 0;
        };
    };

console.log(array.some(even(false)));
```